# Searching for Java MVC Tutorial with more than 1 View

Tags: java, model-view-controller, view, model, controller

Hello i am searching for a Java MVC Tutorial with more than 1 View. So that there is a navigation to a different View when the user, for example, click on a button.

Java with MVC for 1 View is totaly clear for me, but I don't know how to do the navigation.

Thank you in advance, Niklas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a "Root" Controller + JFrame, which holds the actual View(JPanel) + Controller. If I want to navigate I will call a method on my root controller from the actual controller and he is changing the view + all the other stuff.

Every Controller implements a Controller Interface for some operations like initializing the view.

```
RootController knows JFrame
RootController + Controller1 know each other
Controller1 knows View1/Panel1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this tutorial:

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/javamvcdesignpattern.html

In this tutorial a new view ist created by the controller. In case of navigation you have to implement a method "updateMainPanel" in view to show the new content of an other view.

Comment: This tutorial is a bit suspicious to me. This isn't even real MVC. In MVC View and Model has no connection, never ever.